# Removing a Corrupted Ubuntu Installation

Tags: system-installation, uninstall, partitioning

I have a corrupted Ubuntu partition on my computer. Would installing a new copy of Ubuntu and selecting to remove the old OS remove the corrupted copy from my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you choose to overwrite the corrupted partition.

When you got to the `Installation type` section. You would need to select the option: `Replace "OS name" with Ubuntu`. ("OS name" = the name of your OS goes here.)